# TensorFlow: Sample Integers from Gumbel Softmax

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am implementing a program to sample integers from a categorical distribution, where each integer is associated with a probability. I need to ensure that this program is differentiable, so that back propagation can be applied. I found `tf.contrib.distributions.RelaxedOneHotCategorical` which is very close to what I am trying to achieve.

However, the `sample` method of this class returns a one-hot vector, instead of an integer. How to write a program that is both differentiable and returns an integer/scalar instead of a vector?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that RelaxedOneHotCategorical is actually differentiable is connected to the fact that it returns a softmax vector of floats instead of the argmax int index. If all you want is the index of the maximal element, you might as well use Categorical.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a dot product of the relaxed one hot vector with a vector of `[1 2 3 4 ... n]`. The result is going to give you the desired scalar.

For instance if your one hot vector is `[0 0 0 1]`, then `dot([0 0 0 1],[1 2 3 4])` will give you 4 which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get what you want in a differentiable manner because `argmax` isn't differentiable, which is why the Gumbel-Softmax distribution was created in the first place. This allows you, for instance, to use the outputs of a language model as inputs to a discriminator in a generative adversarial network because the activation approaches a one-hot vector as the temperature changes.

If you simply need to retrieve the maximal element at inference or testing time, you can use `tf.math.argmax`. But there's no way to do that in a differentiable manner.